# plugin modal/popup integration best practice

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

I´m writing a plugin that should show a modal popup with a form on a button click.
Now the question is how/where to inject that modal and form HTML?

I can think of these options:

1. Create it with JS. I could add the HTML with wp_add_inline_script() or wp_localize_script in a JS var and append it to the DOM.
2. Create it with JS, but load the form HTML with AJAX from a html or php file.

CON: loading would take a little time

3. echo out a div with display:none.

Question: Where in the document would I output it? I can´t rely on the theme to support wp_footer() and it doesn´t feel right to simply hook it into the_content(). 
What would be a good hook?

thanks

Comment: "I can´t rely on the theme to support wp_footer()" Yes, yes you can. It's absolutely mandatory, and any theme not using it deserves to break.

Answer (score 1):

You should put it inside 'the_content' hook.
1)Create first plugin which has the form that proccess simple form submission.

2)And then call that page in iframe window.Like this:

```
   <---YOU DIV STARTS HERE FOR POPUP WINDOW-->
    <div id="iframeclasses">
    <?php add_thickbox(); ?>

    //Your form link 

    <a  href="YOUR_LINK_GOES_HERE&KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true" class="thickbox">
    </div>
```

3)iframe window open by following code.

```
     <input type="submit" name="submit"  class="button button-primary emailbtn" value="<?php _e('YOUR_BUTON_TEXT', 'TEXTDOMAIN')?>" >
     </div>
    //your div close here
```